Troubles linking QGIS with MySQL database
I need to connect my QGIS project to a MySQL database to do two things:

Recorded point data within QGIS should we synced back to MySQL
Import data from any MySQL table to QGIS (to manage labels and such)

I've tried following this guide:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zP5dE5kht0w
The connection test to my database is successful, however when trying to go to the next step, which should let me access the data, I get an error saying :

MySQL:dbname,host=localhost,port=3306 is not a valid or recognised data source

I've read things about a "MySQL Spatial Extensions" plugin, so I'm looking into that, as maybe QGIS needs a MySQL server that has this plugin to access it, but I struggle to find how to install it. I'm not even sure if it's the correct solution.
Do you have any idea what the problem is, or if there's a better solution?

I am having similar issues, I have checked the connection with other software but QGIS won't connect

https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/479502/23226

Have you saved your authentication as a configuration

Cant believe it was that simple. It works when saving as configuration. Need to make sure said configuration is selected before adding the layer. Thanks

So the solution was:
For my local MySQL database, accessed with only a username and no password, I had to check the "store" checkmark when entering the basic authentication, somehow saving it as configuration doesnt work (the connection fails).
For my distant MySQL server, I had to save the authentication as configuration, then make sure it's selected before clicking "add".
